# Creating embeddings and training on embeddings using a bigram LSTM model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create and train on bigram embeddings for LSTMs in Tensorflow.

We are initially given that train_data is a Tensor of shape `(num_unrollings, batch_size, 27) i.e.`num_unrollings`is the total number of batches,`batch_size`is the size of each batch, and`27` is the size of the one-hot-encoded vector for characters "a" to "z" and including " ".

The LSTM takes as input a single batch at each time step i.e. it takes in a Tensor of shape `(batch_size, 27)`

`characters()` is a function that takes in a Tensor of shape `27` and returns the most likely character that it represents from the one-hot-encodings.

What I have done so far is created an index lookup for each bigram. We have a total of 27*27 = 729 bigrams (because I include the " " character). I choose to represent each bigram by a vector of log(729) ~ 10 bits.

In the end I am trying to make my input to the LSTM a Tensor of shape `(batch_size / 2, 10)`. So that I can train on the bigrams.

Here is the relevant code:

```
batch_size=64
num_unrollings=10
num_embeddings = 729 
embedding_size = 10

bigram2id = dict()

key = ""

# build dictionary of bigrams and their respective indices: 
for i in range(ord('z') - ord('a') + 2): 
    key = chr(97 + i)
    if (i == 26): 
        key = " "
    for j in range(ord('z')- ord('a') + 2):
        if j == 26: 
            bigram2id[key + " "] = i*27 + j 
            continue
        bigram2id[key + chr(97 + j)] = i*27 + j

graph = tf.Graph() 

with graph.as_default(): 

    # embeddings 
    embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([num_embeddings, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0), trainable=False)

    """
    1) load the training data as we would normally 
    2) look up the embeddings of the data then from there get the inputs and the labels 
    3) train
    """

    # load training data, labels for both unembedded and embedded data 
    train_data = list()
    embedded_train_data = list()
    for _ in range(num_unrollings + 1):
        train_data.append(tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size,vocabulary_size]))
        embedded_train_data.append(tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size / 2, embedding_size]))

    # look up embeddings for training data and labels (make sure to set trainable=False) 
    for batch_ctr in range(num_unrollings + 1): 
        for bigram_ctr in range((batch_size // 2) + 1): 
            # get current bigram
            current_bigram = characters(train_data[batch_ctr][bigram_ctr*2]) + characters(train_data[batch_ctr][bigram_ctr*2 + 1])
            # look up id 
            current_bigram_id = bigram2id[current_bigram]
            # look up embedding
            embedded_bigram = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, embedded_bigram)
            # add to current batch 
            embedded_train_data[batch_ctr][bigram_ctr].append(embedded_bigram)
```

But right now, I am getting the Shape (64, 27) must be of rank 1 error and even if I fix that, I am not sure whether I am taking the right approach.